# How to encapsulate style into html template in angularjs?

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, less

I have a web app using AngularJS and Bootstrap. In a page I want to have two components with different styles. For example:

```
<div ng-include="'./component/header.html'"></div>
<div ng-include="'./component/header.html'"></div>
```

I want these 2 divs have different styles. My question is, 1) How can I encapsulate the style code into header.html? 2) How can I use less to define the style?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You might want to look into Shadow DOM

Comment: @timeNomad Hmm, it seems something interesting! Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first question:
Why not give the 2 `div`s a different class and then adopt the CSS like that:

```
<div class="first" ng-include="'./component/header.html'"></div>
<div class="second" ng-include="'./component/header.html'"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.first table {
    /* style definitions */
}

.second table{
    /* style definitions */
}
```

Like in this [Snippet](https://jsfiddle.net/7v25voLc/)

Answer (score 1):

You can add an id or class to each ng-include and style under that selector with css or less. It makes no difference what preprocessor or lack of, you use.

```js
angular.module('app', []);

function HomeCtrl() {

}
```

```css
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header {
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
#header1 {
    background: red;
}
#header2 {
    background: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">

    <div ng-include="'header.html'" id="header1" class="header"></div>
    <div ng-include="'header.html'" id="header2" class="header"></div>

     <script type="text/ng-template" id="header.html">
       header
    </script>
</div>
```